# WSO2 API Manager - API Group inside another group

Tags: tags, wso2, api-manager

Im aware that in order to group APIs, we need to tag tha APIs with desired "suffix"-group in WSO2 Publisher.

Is it possible to create a subgroup within existing API Group?

Answer (score 0):

No, tags are not hierarchical.